# How can I generate a pause and provide feedback updates on the client side while calling a server async method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, file-transfer

I'm refactoring legacy code that updates a progress bar as a file is written from a handheld device to an app running on a server. The legacy code is:

```
public static bool WriteIt2( string fileName, string data, long fsize )
{
    bool         retVal      = false;
    long         nBytes      = 0;
    int          bytRd       = 0; 
    string       the_Msg     = "";
    StringReader sr          = null;
    char[]       theC_buffer = new char[MAXREAD];            
    byte[]       theB_buffer = new byte[MAXREAD];
    . . .
    while( sr.Peek() != -1 )
    {
        if( (bytRd = sr.Read( theC_buffer, 0, MAXREAD )) > 0  )
        {
            nBytes += bytRd;
            realTotBytesRead += bytRd; 
            xferProgress = nBytes.ToString() + "|" + fsize.ToString();
            theB_buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( theC_buffer, 0, bytRd );
            IAsyncResult allDone = theN_Stream.BeginWrite( theB_buffer, 0, theB_buffer.Length, null, null );            
            allDone.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                                    theN_Stream.EndWrite( allDone );
        }

        if( StopCancel )
            break;
    } 
    . . .
```

I want to do something like this:

```
bool retVal = false;
long bytRd = 0;
string the_Msg = "";            

SendXMLFile(fileName, uri, 500);
while( bytRd < fsize )
{
    bytRd += 100; // "100" is just an arbitrary "step" value
    xferProgress = bytRd.ToString() + "|" + fsize.ToString();
    Thread.Sleep(500); // Let the progress bar value display long enough to be visually sensible

    if( StopCancel )
        break;
}
```

I'm afraid that what I'd be doing here is all the real work (in the call to SendXMLFile()) and then "faking" the progress feedback. Is it possible to make the code more "honest" and have the progress/sleep actually occur *while* SendXMLFile() is executing? BTW, the server method being called is async awaitable:

```
[Route("api/platypi/sendXML/{userId}/{pwd}/{filename}")] 
public async void SendPlatypusXML(String userId, String pwd, String fileName)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
    String saveLoc = String.Format(@"C:\duckbill\{0}.xml", fileName);
    doc.Save(saveLoc);
}
```

Comment: Your code is really unclear. What is `SendXMLFile`? where is its code? are you trying to make this code asynchronous?

Comment: SendXMLFile() is listed at the bottom. The first (legacy) code is also very unclear to me; that's one reason it's being refactored.

Comment: The buttom method is called `SendPlatypusXML`. Am i missing something?

Comment: Oh, sorry - SendXMLFile() would just muddy the waters; it sends the XML file - it calls SendPlatypusXML().

Comment: To be clear, your problem is reading the buffer in chunks from the stream and updating the progress bar?

Comment: That's what the old code does; I'm simply calling the REST method that transfer the file. My problem is finding a way to update the progress bar. The old code transfer some data, and then updates the progress bar until the file is transferred. My new code does not loop - it calls an async method.

Comment: If the server code is the one reading from the stream i see no way of making this real. You should return the stream to the client and have it iterate the stream and update the progress bar, assuming you want the progress bar to be updating "for real"

Comment: The file is being sent from the client to the server; I don't want anything back from the server. I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Then if the client knows how much data it has sent, and if it knows the total amount of data, then the _client_ should be doing the progress bar?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Exactly. That's what I show above. But the way I'm doing it is phoney; that's what my question is - how to do it while the async method is running (if it's even possible without practicing voodoo).

Comment: What exactly does `SendXMLFile()` do? How does it give the data to the server?